# Smart fluorescent strip lights

Tags: smart-home, google-home, lighting

Is there a way to turn on and off fluorescent strip lights  using google home.

Most IoT light solutions I have found require bulb replacement, are dimmer switches or are not compatible with this type of lighting. The current switch controls 2 different strip lights to make things more complicated. We are in the UK.

Comment: Do you know what type of lights the strip lights are? LED or fluorescent perhaps? If you can, it would also be helpful to know how the light switch is currently wired, and your country (so we know the voltage of your circuit and the likely wiring setup). It sounds like a smart switch is probably the way, but it'd be a good idea to check that your current switch could support a smart socket; [edit] with what you can find out, and we'll be able to help you a lot more.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the question. fluorescent and based in the uk.

Comment: This may require a clicking relay type of remote switch with appropriate ratings.  They are readily available, but common only in plug-in form, which wouldn't be formally compatible with your lights if they are a permanently wired installation.  Remote switches for installation presumably exist but are likely rarer and more expensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To control fluorescent lights, you should look for a device called an "appliance switch".  This will control any load by switching the power on or off; it does not "dim" the load.  With it, your fluorescent lights will work just like your ordinary switch does today.

Be aware that home automation systems generally do not consider appliance switches to be in the same category as "light" switches.  This is only an issue if you say "Hey Google, turn all the lights on" and expect this switch to be included.  But you can name it "bedroom light", and say "Hey Google, turn the bedroom light on", and it will work.

(Also note that some very old fluorescent light fixtures have a manual starter.  You must press and hold a button until the lights come on.  If that's what you have, no commercial home automation electronics are designed to control them.)

Answer (score 4):

Something like the [Sonoff Basic WiFi Wireless Switch](https://www.itead.cc/sonoff-wifi-wireless-switch.html) from Sonoff, of the order of $5 and has Alexa/Google Home support already should fit your requirements.

It is a Wi-Fi switch that is connected to your home network, and can be operated through the Google Assistant as described [here](https://www.itead.cc/blog/sonoff-work-with-google-home) by connecting the devices to the 'eWeLink' app, and then adding smart home devices to the Google Assistant from 'Smart We Link'.